# TextInput cropped

Tags: python, kivy

When the TextInput is sufficiently small, we are talking 24dp or smaller, the text is automatically cropped to fit inside a certain distance from the borders like this one.

[image]

I do not want to increase its size, and if I decrease the font size more it will be unreadable. I have been modifying the colors and borders of the TextInput, but it doesn't modify this invisible border. I have searched StackOverflow for an answer for a while but I can't find one.

```py
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.layout = FloatLayout()
        self.layout.add_widget(TextInput(pos_hint={'x':.5,'y':.5},
                                         size_hint=(None,None),
                                         size=(100,20)))
class MyApp(App):
    drops = []

    def build(self):

        Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')
        Config.set('kivy', 'exit_on_escape', 0)
        Config.write()

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HomeScreen())
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html) default padding is [6, 6, 6, 6]

Try adding padding = 3 as parameter of the TextInput